# How to solve the error of popper.js in console in Angular2

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, popper.js

i installed angular ng-select, and while running the app i am getting error as

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined
    at scripts.bundle.js:12
```

Can anyone help to solve this error.

**anuglar-cli.json:**

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ],
```

Comment: add popper js as a third party dependency if you are using cli it will be easy to add third party js

Comment: Sorry wrong link please try [this](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using angular-cli and didn't add the dependency to you **anuglar-cli.json**, meaning the reference doesn't get compiled into your project.
So you are able to use it the package.

First you need to add the package to your package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  },
  "scripts": {
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "popper.js": "^1.12.5",

  }
}
```

Or simple run

```
npm install popper.js --save-dev
```

After that step you need to take a look at your **angular-cli.json** file. Look at the following code and take a closer look at the **"scripts"** section:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "appname"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "server/public",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
        "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see that I added the **path** from the **angular-cli.json** to the location where you installed the package.

Try add that section and start up your project again.

**Note:** Popper.js should be included before bootstrap.

Comment: Okay, it need to be there else it Wong get compiled into you project, please do so, and update you answer with the errors please

Comment: shall i clone again and restart from first?

Comment: It's totally up to you, but in my experience. It would be better to read some of the documentation regarding **angular-cli**. I'm positive this is where your problem is.